# When is it appropriate to use virtual methods?

Tags: c++, oop, methods, virtual

I understand that virtual methods allow a derived class to override methods inherited from a base class.  When is it appropriate/inappropriate to use virtual methods?  It's not always known whether or not a class will be sub classed.  Should everything be made virtual, just "in case?"  Or will that cause significant overhead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you design a class you should have a pretty good idea as to whether it represents an interface (in which case you mark the appropriate overrideable methods and destructor virtual) OR it's intended to be used as-is, possibly composing or composed with other objects.

In other words your intent for the class should be your guide. Making everything virtual is often overkill and sometimes misleading regarding which methods are intended to support runtime polymorphism.

Answer (score 10):

First a slightly pedantic remark - in C++ standardese we call them member functions, not methods, though the two terms are equivalent.

I see two reasons NOT to make a member function virtual.

- "YAGNI" - "You Ain't Gonna Need It".  If you are not sure a class will be derived from, assume it won't be and don't make member functions virtual.  Nothing says "don't derive from me" like a non-virtual destructor by the way (edit: In C++11 and up, you have the [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) keyword] which is even better).  It's also about intent.  If it's not your intent to use the class polymorphically, don't make anything virtual.  If you arbitrarily make members virtual you are inviting abuses of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle) and those classes of bugs are painful to track down and solve.
- Performance / memory footprint.  A class that has no virtual member functions does not require a VTable (virtual table, used to redirect polymorphic calls through a base class pointer) and thus (potentially) takes up less space in memory. Also, a straight member function call is (potentially) faster than a virtual member function call.
  Don't prematurely pessimize your class by pre-emptively making member functions virtual.

Answer (score 5):

It's a tricky question. But there are some guidelines / rule of thumbs to follow.

1. As long as you do not need to derive from a class, then don't write any `virtual` method, once you need to derive, only make `virtual` those methods you need to customize in the child class.
2. If a class has a `virtual` method, then the destructor shall be `virtual` (end of discussion).
3. Try to follow NVI (Non-Virtual Interface) idiom, make `virtual` method non-public and provide public wrappers in charge of assessing pre and post conditions, so that derived classes cannot accidentally break them.

I think those are simple enough. I definitely let the ABI part of the reflexion away, it's only useful when delivering DLLs.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is following a particular design pattern, then your choice should reflect the DP's own principles. For example, if you are coding a [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), the function that should be virtual are the ones that belong to the Component interface.

Otherwise, I'd like to follow an evolutional approach, IOW I don't have *virtual* methods until I see that a hierarchy is trying to emerge from your code.

Answer (score 3):

For instance member functions in Java are 100% virtual. In C++ it is considered as a code size/function call time penalty. Additionally a non virtual function guarantees that the function implementation will always be the same (using the base class object/reference). Scott Meyers in "Effective C++" discusses it in more details.

Comment: The fact that a non-virtual function "stays the same" is important for other functions calling it. It is much harder to get the **calling** function correct when there are virtual functions involved.

Answer (score 2):

A sanity test I mostly use is - In case a class I'm defining is derived from in future, would the behavior (function) remain same or would it need to be redefined. If it would be, the function is a strong contender for being virtual, if not then no, if I do not know - I probably need to look into the problem domain for better understanding of behavior I'm planning to implement. Mostly problem domain gives me the answer - in cases where it does not the behavior is *generally* non critical.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one possible way to determine quickly would be to consider if you are going to deal with a bunch of similar classes that you are going to use to perform the same tasks, with the change being the *way* you go about doing those tasks.

One trivial example would be the problem of computing areas for various geometric figures. You need the areas of squares, circles, rectangles, triangles etc. and the only thing that changes here is the math formulae (the way) you use to compute the area. Therefore it would be a good decision to have each of these shapes inherit from a common base class and to add a virtual method in the base class that returns the area (which you can then implement in each of the child with the respective math formula).

Making everything virtual "just in case" will make your objects take up more memory. Additionally, there is a small (but non-zero) overhead when calling virtual functions. So, IMHO, making everything virtual "just in case" would be bad idea when performance/memory constraints are important (which basically means in always every real-world program that you write).

However, this again is debatable based on how clearly the requirements are spelled out and how often code-changes expected. For example, in a quick-and-dirty tool or an initial prototype where a few extra bytes of memory and a few milliseconds of lost time do not mean much, it would be OK to have a bunch (unnecessarily) virtual functions for the sake of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

My point is if you want to use the parent class pointer to point at child class instance and use their methods, then you should use virtual methods.

Comment: While true, I don't think this really answers the larger question of "how do I know that I'll need polymorphism?"

Answer (score 0):

Virtual methods are a way to achieve polymorphism. They are used when you want to define some action at a more abstract level such that it is impossible to actually implement because it is too general. Only in derived classes you can tell how to perform that action. But with the definition of a virtual method you create a requirement, that adds rigidity to the hierarchy of classes. This can advisable or not, it depends on what you are trying to obtain, and on your own taste.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). If your code/design is one of these or similar go use virtual function. Otherwise, try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80045/Composition-VS-Inheritance.aspx)

Comment: -1:  there is no causality relationship between wanting to implement a GoF design pattern and the need for virtual functions.